# R - how append newlines to plotted text

Tags: r, string, plot

Say I have a plot in R:

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n');
```

And I have a vector of comments:

```
comments = c("cool use of a string", "wow", "very very interesting")
```

And then I want to plot some text:

```
text(x = 0, y = 0.5, comments, cex = 0.9, col = "black", adj=0);
```

This is going to overwrite each line at the same position, causing a black blurry mess. It also exceeds the number of characters I'd like to see on each line. I can call strwrap, of course, but adding a "\n" prefix doesn't add the newlines as I'd like.

```
text(x = 0, y = 0.5, strwrap(comments, width=15, prefix="\n"), cex = 0.9, col = "black", adj=0);
```

My question: How do I plot an array of strings so that each line is wrapped at, say, 15 characters, and each string is plotted on a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `paste` in the following way and it will show fine:

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')

comments = c("cool use of a string", "wow", "very very interesting")

text(x = 0, y = 0.5, paste(strwrap(comments, width=15, prefix="\n"),collapse=''), 
     cex = 0.9, col = "black", adj=0);
```

So, literally the only thing needed is to use `paste` to convert the vector produced from `strwrap` into a single string which is then plotted. Remember to use `collapse=''` so that the single string has no characters in between.

Output (blank plot with only the words; as you designed/wanted it):

[image]

Comment: Wow, you posted that just as I cracked the problem myself! The key was that I didn't realise that strwrap returns an array of strings, each the specified number of characters long. I'd always called it wrapped in writeLines, which hid the structure from me.

Comment: Great! Well this will be even better then because usually things we solve ourselves, we tend to remember even more easily. That was the exact problem as you described it. Well, I 'm glad you solved it yourself, this can then work as a verification that your method was correct :P. Sorry, I didn't see it sooner :)